# How to download NYC-TLC-GREEN_2015/2014 public data sets to my local system from google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to **download NYC-TLC-GREEN_2015/2014 public data sets to my local system from google cloud**?

Answer (score 0):

The **BigQuery Public Datasets** make reference to any dataset that is stored in BigQuery and that are made available to the general public **through the Google Cloud Public Dataset Program**, as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data). These resources are hosted for you to access and integrate into your applications; however, I think it is not possible to download to your local environment.

In case you strongly require this information, I recommend you to contact them by using the information displayed at the [Contact us](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/#contact_us) page in order to get detailed information about the available alternatives to access to these resources.